# What does "world order" mean here

Tags: meaning

> Conspiracists have  long speculated that these individuals are part of **a secret “world  order”**, with ties to the Illuminati and satanic cults. Debunking these  theories is relatively easy, but in his new book John Dickie goes much  further. Based on years of research into the archives of the Grand  Lodges, he has produced a global history of the organisation, explaining how the brand spread far beyond Europe. “The Craft” is a fascinating  tale of imperial trade, warfare and scientific progress which presents  the Masons as a response to the broader development of the modern world.

---

I found in dictionary a definition : *[social/political order] - the political, social, or economic situation at a particular time*

But how can individuals be part of a situation, what does "world order" mean?

article link :　https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2020/08/29/a-global-history-of-the-freemasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conspiracists believe that various groups (many of which want to exterminate each other) are secretly working together to manipulate world events and *bring about* a New World Order, which is not well defined but embodies whatever the conspiracists happen to fear most at the moment.

They sometimes refer to these groups, rather than their plan, as being the New World Order. This is incorrect usage, but given their lack of common sense and logic, a lack of grammar skills too is not surprising.